# Get Number of Entities and its Fields Programmaticaly, Data-driven Application

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I want to create a dynamic datadriven application for practice purposes.

If I have a Modell with a Entity and I need a new one, then I want to create it only in the Diagram (modell) and thats all.

Everything else should be done dynamically, adding the new entity to b.e a Listbox, make it clickable and create a "Show Datas" and a "New/Edit" Tab with the right labels and textboxes in it. (For editing/creating new)

What I would like to know is, how can I:

1. Get the number of the entities
2. Is it possible to update the database, without needing to delete it and create new (Else I would loose all Data), if hopefully yes, how?
3. Get all the fields from a Entity? (Do I must work here with Reflection?)

Hope someone could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.Get the number of the entities**

Using Context object you get the list of entities. there you can use the .Count() to check the no of entities of that type.

**2.Is it possible to update the database, without needing to delete it and create new (Else I would loose all Data), if hopefully yes, how?**

This question is little unclear. you want to delete database.. or entity?? you can do any operation on entities that will be reflected on back end if you want. Regarding database delete and create operation, entity framework is not designed for.

Yes you can add new entity to model and then map it with the back end tables.. it is possible to modify the model as per your backend. Even you can create you custom entites that reflect operation on multiple tables on the database but with some care about data integration.

**3.Get all the fields from a Entity? (Do I must work here with Reflection?)**

Yes.. To access the properties of Entity with out knowing their name you should go through reflection.

Comment: thx for the answers.. For 2.: If you add a new Entity, it's so that the Database must be regenerated, that changes are effective. I would like to know if its possible, to only UPDATE the Modell (And the Database), without loosing any data in the Database. (Working here with SQL Compact 4.0, but thats not necessary anyway)

Comment: yes you can modify the model as per you backend change.. explorer more about entity framework at MSDN.